# How to programmatically set environment variable to be a secret in postman?

Tags: postman

The docs go over how to do this manually, but I'd like to do this via a script.
https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/#variable-types

It doesn't seem like [the `pm.environment.set` method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tijOX.png) would work here. I tried a few values for the third argument (like "secret") before I realized this was the case.

Comment: It seems this feature has not developed yet. Check this https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10580